# What are some easy methods to cook a top blade steak without stock or wine?

Tags: steak

I would like to ask about cooking a top blade steak. I am currently out of stock and wine, and am curious about slow cooking it in an oven, although not really familiar with slow cooking. Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you got any beer? Fruit juice?

Answer (score 2):

water, seasonings, aromatics vegetables (carrots, celery, onions garlic... ), tomato paste and/or canned tomatoes

Brown the meat in oil in a dutch oven type pan, remove and set aside.

Brown the vegetables in oil, when good you have coloring (not burning), add tomato paste, mix and cook well for a few minutes.

Add meat back to the pot, add water and canned tomatoes to nearly cover the meat.

Reduce heat, cover with a lid and cook until meat is tender, adjust water level so it does not dry out during cooking

You can do it on the cooktop or in the oven.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to have stock or wine, meat becomes tender with slow cooking in the presence of water as the water helps to break down the connective tissue that makes meat tough. Stock or wine is just water with flavor, but you can add flavor in any number of ways through spices, herbs, vegetables and other ingredients.

You can slow cook in the oven or on a burner, the key is to have a lid on the pot or dish to keep the moisture sealed in. I personally prefer the oven as it gives me better control over heat, and I don't have to worry about the bottom burning as in the oven the heating is even across the entire dish.